# 2d bitmap being filled with objects in incorrect locations [Homework]

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, bitmap

For homework, I have to build a 10x10 "bitmap" that will print a simple image of a house, built as its own class. The constructor requires an `int[]` filled with the coordinates of each point, in such a way that the values `1 , 1 , 1 , 2` are equivalent to the coordinate points (1,1) and (1,2)

But I am baffled as to what is happening when I try to print my array. Some of my points are in the wrong spots, some are missing, but the majority are in the correct location. After being populated and printed, the bitmap is supposed to look like

```
---------                      ----------
-o-oo----                      -o-o------
-oo--o---                      -oo-o-----
-o----o--                      -o---o----
oo----oo-                      oo----o---
-o-o--o--   but my result is   -o-o---o--
-o-o--o--                      -o-o--o---
-o-o--o--                      -o-o--o---
-oooooo--                      -oooooo---
---------                      ----------
```

The following is my constructor...

```
String image[][] = new String[10][10];

Bitmap(int a[]) {
    //CONSTRUCTOR

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //set all to '-'

      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        image[i][j] = "-";

      }

    }

    int c = 0; // because it takes too long to type out a proper for loop
    for (int i : a) { //read data and plot points

      if(c % 2 == 1)  temp2 = a[c];
      else temp1 = a[c];


      if(c % 2 == 0 && c != 0)
        image[temp1][temp2] = "o";
      c++;
    }
  }
```

and here are my points.

```
int points[] = { 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 6, 4, 0, 4, 1, 4, 6, 4, 7, 5,
                 1, 5, 3, 5, 6, 6, 1, 6, 3, 6, 6, 7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 6, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 
                 8, 5, 8, 6
```

which translate to:

```
(1,1) (1,3) (1,4) (2,1) (2,2) (2,5) (3,1) (3,6) (4,0) (4,1) (4,6) (4,7) (5,1) (5,3) (5,6)
(6,1) (6,3) (6,6) (7,1) (7,3) (7,6) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8,6)
```

My result, on the other hand, prints as

```
(1,1) (1,3) ( , ) (2,1) (2,2) (2,4) (3,1) (3,5) (4,0) (4,1) (4,6) ( , ) (5,1) (5,3) (5,7)
(6,1) (6,3) (6,6) (7,1) (7,3) (7,6) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8,6)
```

I can't tell what I am doing wrong and don't really know where to start. It would be great if I could get a few pointers or maybe a comment on a flaw in my code.

Comment: First of all I suggest naming your variables maybe `int x` and `int y`. And I do wonder why you are setting the Bitmap-point to `o` when `c % 2 == 0` should'nt you test for `if (c % 2 != 0)`?

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker Thank you, that worked. After reading your suggestion, I traced through my code again and I realized why your answer is correct. If I was testing for `c % 2 == 0 && c != 0`, then I would start printing `o` on the _third_ iteration instead of on the _second_ iteration. The second iteration would be the first time a complete set is made, and the third iteration would be one number after the complete set is made. This also makes me able to exclude the `c != 0` from my `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all I suggest naming your variables maybe `int x` and `int y`. And I do wonder why you are setting the Bitmap-point to `o` when `c % 2 == 0` should'nt you test for if `(c % 2 != 0)`? –Schokokuchen Bäcker

This comment by [Schokokuchen Bäcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692099/schokokuchen-b%C3%A4cker) solved the problem.

In the loop above, the line `if(c % 2 == 0 && c != 0)` is starting to set `[temp1][temp2] = "o"` on the **third** iteration rather than the **second** iteration, which results in one point being excluded at the very beginning of the code.